# Switching Files Between Directories with CUI (mv command)

Tags: mv

I am currently working through "The Command Line Crash Course" and am having trouble switching files to my desktop.

In the terminal I create a new file (awesome.txt).

I see awesome on my desktop and then I make a directory (something).

I then do:
 mv awesome.txt something/

When I open the something directory in my GUI, the awesome.txt is present.  Now I want to take the awesome.txt and put it back on my desktop screen. So I try the same command and format I used to get it into the something directory

mv awesome.txt desktop/

I get an error "mv: rename awesome.txt to desktop/: No such file or directory"

NOW i found this command online, and it takes awesome.txt and puts it back on my desktop from the something directory

mv awesome.txt ../  (it moves it back to the last directory it is in)

Can anyone explain why I can't use the name desktop/ to put it back on my desktop screen? Is the desktop classified as something different than a file or directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the name "desktop/" refers to a directory called desktop that's inside your "something" directory.  But the actual desktop folder is outside of your "something" directory, so you need to tell mv to look there instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the `something` directory `desktop/` is relative to that directory, so it would be looking for `something/desktop/` which obviously doesn't exist.

`../` just means drop back a level, which is the desktop from the `something` directory.

you could try `/desktop/` from the `something` directory, but you may want to try `cd /desktop/` first to see where it takes you in case `/desktop` is not the actual root.

Comment: I am starting to see what you all mean about it not being relative to the proper directory. Here is what I tried.  cd desktop, then i did ls and saw something was listed, wouldn't this mean they are in the same path?

Comment: does cd / work? or is it just cd does not mean change directory in CUI

Comment: I can use cd to get into my desktop, for instance as long as I am not in a current directory, I can use cd to go into any directory. So I input cd desktop, then pwd and it shows desktop.

Comment: if i am in my desktop directory, and then use the cd command to a different directory I get a bash error. I have to do cd (then press enter) to leave whatever directory I am in. Then I can put in something besides desktop to move to a different directory.